# iOS で日本円を入力する UI コンポーネント

Tags: ios

今、 iOS アプリを開発していて、日本円を入力する UIView が欲しくなりました。たとえば unix などでも、 例えば LC_MONETARY が広く普及していることを考えると、対象の国、というかロケールに対して金額を取り扱うライブラリの需要は高いのではないか、と思っています。そして、需要が高いのならば、おそらくそういうライブラリは既存で存在している可能性が高い、とも考えています。既にあるならば、車輪の再発明は避けたいです。

質問:

- 日本円を入力するような UIView を含むような、ライブラリはありますか?
- ただの UITextField からスタートするとすると、以下のようなことをやりたくなり、いかにも再発明っぽいな、と思っているので質問しています。

  - エンマークを頭もしくは後ろに付与する
  - 数字だけが入力されるように制限をかける
  - 三桁ごとに `,` を表示する
  - `moneyInput.value` などのようにすると入力内容が数値として取り出せる

Comment: 「UITextField + currency」などをキーワードに検索するとたくさん見つかります。iOSにはNumberFormatterというLocaleに応じて通貨形式のフォーマットをしてくれるクラスがあるので、これらのライブラリはそれを使用しています。